# How can I trigger change event in this case using Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to change the content of a dropdown using the selection of another dropdown. The HTML code is as follow.

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="makesel">Make</label>
        <select [ngModel]="vehicle.makeId" class="form-control" id="makesel" (ngModelChange)="onChangeMake($event.target.value)">
            <option>Choose a make</option>
            <option *ngFor="let make of makes" [value]="make.id">{{ make.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="currentMake" class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="make">Model</label>
        <select [ngModel]="vehicle.modelId"  class="form-control" id="model">
            <option>Choose a model</option>
            <option *ngFor="let model of currentMake.models" value="{{ model.id }}">{{ model.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the component is coded as follow:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
selector: 'register-form',
templateUrl: './registerform.component.html'
})
export class RegisterFormComponent{
public makes: Make[];
public currentMake: Make;
public vehicle: Vehicle;

constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string){
    http.get(baseUrl + 'api/makes').subscribe(result => {
        this.makes = result.json() as Make[];
    }, error => console.error(error));
    this.vehicle = new Vehicle();
};

onChangeMake(makeId : number){
    console.log("test");
    this.currentMake = this.makes.filter(x => x.Id == makeId)[0];
}
}

class Make {
Id: number;
Name: string;
Models: Model[];
}

class Model{
Id: number;
Name: string;
}

class Vehicle{
makeId : number;
modelId : number;
registered: boolean;
features: number[];
contactName: string;
contactPhone: string;
contactEmail: string;
}
```

The problem is that the change event is not working in anyway I try. The current code is using ngModel and ngModelChange, but I also tried using only

```
change="onChangeMake($event.target.value)"
```

But I didn't have success as well. It seems like the method "onChangeMake" are not been called. Since I didn't find different ways to do this besides those two and neither seems to work, I'm asking some help. Am I missing something?

For reference:
Angular version: 4.2.5
TypeScript version: 2.6.2

Thanks in advance for the answer!

Comment: Can you pass one of the values of make array in ngModel? I believe we should pass one of the values from the values passing to the option tag to select ngModel for making it working perfectly. If we pass one of the value to the ngModel than after each selection the variable passed to the ngModel is going to contain the updated value. Right now, you are passing the two different type of values to select and option tag whereas both of them belong to each other.

Comment: I think it should be [(ngModel)]="..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use two-way binding with `[(ngModel)]`, setting the `make` items as option values with `[ngValue]`:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="makesel">Make</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="currentMake" class="form-control" id="makesel" name="makesel">
            <option>Choose a make</option>
            <option *ngFor="let make of makes" [ngValue]="make">{{ make.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="currentMake" class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="model">Model</label>
        <select [(ngModel)]="vehicle.modelId"  class="form-control" id="model" name="model">
            <option>Choose a model</option>
            <option *ngFor="let model of currentMake.models" [value]="model.Id">{{ model.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your template, you use `currentMake.models`, `model.id` and `model.name`, but these fields are defined in your code as `currentMake.Models`, `model.Id` and `model.Name`. You should define your classes as:

```
class Make {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    models: Model[];
}

class Model{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

For debugging, you can also define `currentMake` as a property:

```
private _currentMake: Make;

public get currentMake(): Make {
    return this._currentMake;
}
public set currentMake(value: Make) {
    console.log("Setting currentMake", value);
    this._currentMake = value;
}
```

Comment: I tried this approach on my project and it didn't work. It is so strange because it is correct for me, too... Maybe it is configuration problem?

Comment: I updated my answer. Some field names used in the template don't match the names in your class definitions. I also suggest defining `currentMake` as a property for debugging. One more thing: look at the console to see if there are any error messages when you run the application.

Comment: Nothing seems to work. One error I'm getting though is this one:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js:3849)
    ...
    ...

It looks like jQuery is not defined, but this can have a real consequence? It was there since the beginning and the http request works just fine, the entire application works as expected despite that.

Comment: My suggestion for that problem would be to uninstall your current version of Bootstrap and to replace it with an Angular version, like [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). That component library does not need jQuery at all. After installing ng-bootstrap, you would need to install only the Bootstrap CSS, without the associated Javascript code. The bonus: the ng-bootstrap components work better with Angular than the ones based on jQuery.

Comment: I see that you are at Angular 4.2.5. In order to use ng-bootstrap, you would have to upgrade to Angular 5 or to install a previous version of ng-bootstrap, like version 1.0.0-beta.5.

Comment: It was some error on the project, indeed. I made a new project and copied everything to the new one. The error I mentioned disappeared and it is now working with your code solution. I think I messed up anywhere around the prep steps and confused the project. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @ConnorsFan, you can simply use `[(ngModel)]` but if for some reason you sill need to use `ngModelChange`, you'll have to pass the whole `$event` since it contains the current value.

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ly8gpw)**

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="makesel">Make</label>
        <select [ngModel]="vehicle.makeId" class="form-control" id="makesel" (ngModelChange)="onChangeMake($event)">
            <option>Choose a make</option>
            <option *ngFor="let make of makes" [value]="make.Id">{{ make.Name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="currentMake" class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="make">Model</label>
        <select [ngModel]="vehicle.modelId"  class="form-control" id="model">
            <option>Choose a model</option>
            <option *ngFor="let model of currentMake.models" value="{{ model.id }}">{{ model.name }}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your example the event trigger is working, but the dropdown is not updating. I added some models to see if it would work, and it doesn't. On my project it didn't work...

Comment: @leonardo.teteo you need to write [(ngModel)] in the above answer to enable 2-way binding. In this way, your dropdown will start updating.